# Cannot load traced_torch_model_pt in C++

Tags: c++, model, inference, torchscript

I tried to load pre-built traced_torch_model.pt to C++; however, the error message showed "example-app.exe" existed with code -1
Please see below my code snippets and error message screenshot.
I appreciate your input.
[image: error_message_screenshot]

```
using namespace std;
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: example-app <C:\\Users\\C at work\\0813_2021\\traced_torch_model.pt\\>n";
            return -1;
    }

    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    try {
        // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
        module = torch::jit::load(argv[1]);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Model " << argv[1] << " loaded fine\n";

    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::randn({ 1, 1, 64, 101 }));

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    std::cout << output << "\n";
    int y_hat = output.argmax(1).item().toInt();
    std::cout << "Predicted class: " << y_hat << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with python

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow! Just as a general note as you are new, it's better to copy/paste the output of a terminal into a code block rather than a screenshot. This allows others to copy/paste your error and google things etc. It also just renders nicer and takes up less space on the page.